# JavaScript: Retrieve key names from an object?

Tags: javascript, object

Say I have this:

```
var x = {  
          a:{a1:"z", a2:"x"},
          b:{b1:"y", b2:"w"}
}
```

Is there a way to iterate over x to get "a" and "b"?

I want the member name, not its content (I don't want to get `{a1:"z", a2:"x"}`).

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var names = [];
for(var key in x) {
   if(x.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      names.push(key);
   }
}
alert(names.join(', ')); //a, b
```

Comment: Guys, sorry about the undefined `k` typo. I **meant** `key`. :)